# Memory of Java application started from Netbeans

Tags: java, memory, netbeans-7

I have given quite some memory (1024Mb) to an application started within NetBeans, using the run property of my project. Yet my NetBeans config only allows about 800mb. All of this is well within the 4GB of my laptop.

Yet, the application is swapping like crazy. When I lower its memory to about 300mb, it does not swap anymore.

Does NetBeans and the applications started within NetBeans share the same 'slice' of allocated memory? Or what could cause my application to swap intensively?